How to retrieve app's directory when running/configuring Electron.NET portable app?
I have the following Electron.NET app:
using System.Reflection;
using ElectronNET.API;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseElectron(args);
builder.Services.AddElectron();
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "appsettings.json"));

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
await app.StartAsync();

BrowserWindow browserWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync(app.Configuration["Url"]);
browserWindow.SetMenuBarVisibility(false);
browserWindow.Maximize();

app.WaitForShutdown();

Among other settings, electron.manifest.json contains:
"win": {
  "target": "portable"
}

Now I do the following:

Bundle the app via electronize build /target win.
Copy the bundled app into C:\temp.
Create the file appsettings.json with the following content:

{
  "Url": "https://www.google.com"
}


Run the app.

The settings file C:\temp\appsettings.json will not be picked up by the app as Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location points to a temporary directory in which the Electron.NET app is extracted.
How can I retrieve the path from where a portable Electron.NET app starts originally (i.e. C:\temp)?
